# Redo inside if in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, if-statement, conditional-statements, redo

I inherited this code from a former co-worker, and it's giving me `Invalid redo (SyntaxError)` on the `redo`. Was there an older version of Ruby where this would've worked? I've tried 3, 2.7, 2.5, and 2.3, all without success.

```
def check_rate_limit(client, x, spinner)
    if client.rate_limit.remaining <= x
        spinner.error('ERROR: Rate limit exceeded!')
        spinner = TTY::Spinner.new("[:spinner] Rate limit resets in #{client.rate_limit.resets_in + 10} seconds ...", format: :classic)
        spinner.auto_spin

        sleep(client.rate_limit.resets_in + 10) # additional 10 second cooldown

        spinner.success

        spinner = TTY::Spinner.new("[:spinner] Continuing ...", format: :classic)

        redo
    end
end
```

(Replacing `if` with `while` seems to do the trick, but my co-workers code ran before and I want to know why...)

Comment: Ruby 1.8 would allow a stray `redo` in a method body. However, I can't think of a way to actually _call_ such method without getting a `LocalJumpError`.